# how to stream webcam video using C# with rtsp or other?

Tags: c#-4.0, video-streaming, webcam, rtsp

I want to make a application to stream my webcam video. I want to see the webcam video using my android phone. webcam is connected to my PC. I tried this codes but visual studio professional 2012 and ozeki new version not support for this video. I like to make a application like this. please help me. sorry for my bad English. thank  you.

[video link youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NebGpM7P-mA)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey Wisnshaftler, This site is intended to help you solve troubles you are having with your code, not suggest architectures for brand new problems.  So you have specific code that you need assistance with? If not, this question is a bit too broad.

Comment: what is the site some codes are error that videos